Print AUC in my multiple ROC Curves from ggroc
this is my 3 ROC Curves !
rocs <- list()
rocs[["modele1"]] <- roc(data3$USI3, predict(modele1))
rocs[["modele2"]] <- roc(data3$USI3, predict(modele2))
rocs[["modele3"]] <- roc(data3$USI3, predict(modele3))
ggroc (rocs, legacy.axes = TRUE)


How can I directly integrate the AUC values ​​of the 3 models in the “name” part?
Thanks !

By "name part", do you mean the labels of the legend? For example it would write "modele1 AUC=0.XX", "modele2 AUC=0.XX", "modele3 AUC=0.XX"?

@YacineHajji Yes, that’s it! You are awesome, thank you very much!

Please find an a reproducible example using the aSAH dataset.
It will also work with your data.
The idea is to modify the name of each component of your list, computing the AUC.
##### Initiating data
data(aSAH)

##### Initiating ROC curves
rocs <- list()
rocs[[1]] <- roc(aSAH$outcome, aSAH$s100b)
rocs[[2]] <- roc(aSAH$outcome, aSAH$wfns)

##### Modifying list names
for(i in 1:length(rocs)){
  names(rocs)[i] <- paste("modele", i, "AUC=", round(auc(rocs[[i]]), 2))
}

##### Display results
ggroc (rocs, legacy.axes=TRUE)



You brighten my day, thank you so much!
